# Key error (missing column) during network build

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I am trying to follow this approach for identifying transverse nodes. Unfortunately I am getting this error:

```
KeyError: 'Source_Attrib'
```

**Code:**

```
import networkx as nx
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'Node', 'Target')
df_pos = nx.spring_layout(G,k = 0.3) 

nx.draw_networkx(G, df_pos)
plt.show()

# Iterate through all edges
nx.set_node_attributes(G, labels, "Source_Attrib")
for v, w in G.edges:
    print(v)
    # Compare `Label` property of edge endpoints
    # Set edge `internal` property to True if they match
    if G.nodes[v]["Source_Attrib"] == G.nodes[w]["Target_Attrib"]: # Two nodes are directly connected
        G.edges[v, w]["internal"] = True
    else:
        G.edges[v, w]["internal"] = False
```

Dataset:

```
Source  Target  Weight  Target_Attrib   Source_Attrib
143 n1  emerysmith.net  6.9 -0.5    -0.5
155 n2  n3  25.6    -1.0    -1.0
156 n2  n3  15.6    -1.0    -1.0
157 n2  n6  14.5    -1.0    -1.0
158 n3  n2  11.6    -0.5    -1.0
180 n3  n4  25.6    -1.0    -1.0
183 n6  n6  8.6 -0.5    -1.0
184 n6  n3  8.4 -1.0    -1.0
230 n7  n6  11.4    -1.0    -0.5
231 n8  n6  10.9    -1.0    -0.5
```

I would like to visualize the output like in this post: https://www.fatalerrors.org/a/python-networkx-learning-notes.html, where nodes in between two classes are linked to different classes (in the example on the link, these nodes have dashed line).

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-155-25042fae7842> in <module>
      6     # Set edge `internal` property to True if they match
----> 7     if G.nodes[v]["Source_Attrib"] == G.nodes[w]["Label_Sim_urls"]: # Two nodes are directly connected
      8         G.edges[v, w]["internal"] = True
      9     else:

KeyError: 'Source_Attrib'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently don't read the columns source/target attribute. For example, you can simply read them as edge attribute and then loop once over the edges:

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'Node', 'Target', edge_attr=True, create_using=nx.DiGraph)
for edge in G.edges:
    u, v = edge
    G.nodes[u]["Source_Attrib"] = G[u][v]["Source_Attrib"]
    G.nodes[v]["Source_Attrib"] = G[u][v]["Target_Attrib"]
```

Assumes that the data is correct as you may override the attributes multiple times. If needed, you may want to cast it back to an undirected graph.

Comment: Hi Sparky05 thank you so much. Unfortunately I am getting now this error: TypeError: 'AtlasView' object does not support item assignment

Comment: I've now fixed it: `G.nodes[u]["Source_Attrib"]` instead of `G[u]["Source_Attrib"]`